# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: NO

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.5

There are similar questions out there to this one, but I am not finding anything that is solving my issue.

I am working on a django project and made a database change and want to migrate the database change to production. So I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But I receive this error

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

From what I understand I must not have permission to run the migration, but I did try

```
grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

and different combinations thereof, but to no avail.

In my local_settings.py I have

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'NAME': 'stratinvnet',
    },
}
```

I've tried to change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` and that seems to make no difference. I have also tried to remove the password from the `DATABASES` object.

For what it's worth, here is my `GRANTS` table in mysql.

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5FE8B16533FAE91D61522C9A6811F3F709147255' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

and here is the user table.

```
 user       | host      | password                                  |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root       | localhost | *5FE8B16533FAE91D61522C9A6811F3F709147255 |
| root       | 127.0.0.1 |                                           |
| root       | ::1       |                                           |
|            | localhost |                                           |
| root       | %         | *944B67F866A66B9DDD96024A97EBFDC886FC41F6 |
| phpmyadmin | localhost | *5FE8B16533FAE91D61522C9A6811F3F709147255 |
```

Comment: But it says you're not using a password.

Comment: Exactly. So what am I doing wrong? Is there a way to grant permissions without identifying by a password? I tried to leave that part blank, but doing so didn't prevent the error.

Comment: Do I need to run the migration and pass a password to manage.py?

Comment: You should try use the root and password to login mysql like mysql -u root -p, to see if success or not.

Comment: What is `common.py` and how is it being imported into the rest of your project?

Comment: @Aison can log in using root and password directly into mysql. That's no problem.

Comment: @solarissmoke common.py is just for my local machine. It's the second database object that the server looks to. Perhaps I should just delete common.py from my question.

Comment: There must be something overriding your `DATABASES` setting. What other apps do you have installed?

Comment: @solarissmoke well, I tried to just migrate the specific table `python manage.py specific_table` but I got the same error.

Comment: Also notice that I made some edits to provide more information I'm hoping will be helpful.

Comment: You may try delete your app's migrations file then run makemigrations migrate again.

Comment: @Aison I think this is worth trying. I don't believe that my version has a `makemigrations` option, though. In that case do I just use `schemamigration`?

Comment: What is your django version? Did you use South for migrations?

Comment: @Aison Yes. I have `south`, but the django version is just 1.5.5.

Comment: I'm not familiar with south, but you could try use schemamigration yourapp --initial (backup the migration files first)

Comment: You know, @Aison, I see that the proper migration files have been copied over and I have this working on both my local machine and the beta environment. Just not production. I am going to try to re-run `schemamigration` with the `--auto --update` flag and see what happens. I appreciate you sticking with me. This has been a major problem for us.

Comment: I almost feel like I'm getting somewhere. Doing what I said I would just above this comment gave me the message that the new fields had been added, but right after saying they had been added, I received the same error and going into mysql and doing a describe on the table showed that the new fields weren't there. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121471/discussion-between-aison-and-matt-cremeens).

Answer (score 0):

seems like you use socks file for mysql, try replace:

```
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
```

with this:

```
'HOST': '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock',  # 'HOST': 'localhost',
```